# How to force unlock a file on weka?

Tags: linux, weka

When I try to flock some file on a [weka file system](https://docs.weka.io/overview/about) it failed because some other client has already hold the lock, I can't find out which process/host locked it. How can I force the client to unlock the file on weka?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there's no way to unlock a file from a client for a network file system, not NFS and I assume that other file systems as well. Some file systems allow [releasing locks](https://people.redhat.com/rpeterso/Patches/NFS/NLM/004.txt) from the server side.

On the client the only way you can achieve this is to `mv` the file and create a new file with the same name and content but a different inode:

```
mv $FILE $FILE.locked; cp -p $FILE.locked $FILE
```

This will rename the locked file and add it a `.locked` suffix, and than copy it back to the original filename. Now you'll have a file with the same content and attributes as the original file, but since it will have a new inode it will not be locked (The `.locked` file with the original inode, however, will still remain locked).

You should understand the implications of that, though: If there are processes that still hold file descriptors to the original file (either on the same client or other clients), they will now hold a file descriptor to the old file with the `.locked` suffix and not to the new file with the same name, so any change you perform in the new file will not be reflected in those processes. Only processes that a file with that name **after** the `mv` / `cp` will use the new file.